# How to create a Jersey Jax-RS resource request-level init method

Tags: java, jersey, jax-rs

I have a JaxWS resource that needs to process a header param into a complex object.  For simplicity, assume that a ParamConverterProvider instance has already been registered with the application separately, which builds an instance of MyComplexObject given a String input properly.

I would like to have a method which executes before any resource method, to perform some common initialization.  I can't figure out any way to write this method, short of manually invoking it as the first line from every single resource method.

Using @PostConstruct (as illustrated below) does not work, because it executes too early.  The ResourceInfo is not yet available (since there is not yet any request).

```
@Path("/my-resource")
@Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
public abstract class MyResource {
    @Context
    private ResourceInfo resource;

    @HeaderParam("my-complex-obj")
    private MyComplexObject complexObject;

    @PostConstruct
    public final void init() {
        if (resource.getResourceClass().isAnnotationPresent(Annotation.class)) {
            // perform some logic using complexObject
        }
    }

    @GET
    @Path("/my-method")
    public final void myMethod() throws Exception {
        // do stuff
    }

}
```

Another way I imagined this could work is by writing a separate Filter to do the work as shown below.  However, this does not work because the @HeaderParam is only allowed in resource classes.

```
@Provider
@Priority(Priorities.USER)
public class MyFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {
    @Context
    ResourceInfo resource;

    @HeaderParam("my-complex-obj")
    private MyComplexObject complexObject;

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext ctx) throws IOException {
            if (resource.getResourceClass().isAnnotationPresent(Annotation.class)) {
                // perform some logic using complexObject
            }
    }
}
```

Any suggestions on how I can accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

How about using HttpHeaders?
http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ws/rs/core/HttpHeaders.html

```
import javax.ws.rs.core.HttpHeaders;    

@Provider
@Priority(Priorities.USER)
public class MyFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {

@Context
ResourceInfo resource;

@Context
HttpHeaders httpHeader;

@Override
public void filter(ContainerRequestContext ctx) throws IOException {
        if (resource.getResourceClass().isAnnotationPresent(Annotation.class)) {
            // perform some logic using complexObject
        }}
```